# Getting black screen using Tab Bar controller in objective c

Tags: ios

I have this code to display a tab bar controller which have 2 tabs and it works fine.

**MainViewController.h**

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[Class1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Class1" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[Class2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Class2 " bundle:nil];

[getUI navigationAppearance];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];

//object to customize tabBar
[getUI customTabBar:self.tabBarController];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.tabBarController animated:YES];
self.tabBarController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

And in Class1 class which is the Tab1, it has a button to AnotherClass1 and in ANotherClass1 it has a button to AnotherClass3. NOw the problem is that, in AnotherClass3 it has a button to go back in MainViewController.h

**AnotherClass3.h**

```
//This for loop iterates through all the view controllers in navigation stack.

for (UIViewController* viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {

    //This if condition checks whether the viewController's class is MyGroupViewController
    // if true that means its the MyGroupViewController (which has been pushed at some point)
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]] ) {

        // Here viewController is a reference of UIViewController base class of MyGroupViewController
        // but viewController holds MyGroupViewController  object so we can type cast it here
        //self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        MenuViewController *groupViewController = (MenuViewController*)viewController;
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:groupViewController.tabBarController animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Note that when I go back to MainViewController.h, it will display the 2 Tabs.

In testing 20 times, 19 will work normal but 1 will get black screen, i dont know why, I really need your help. Thanks

Comment: hey anybody can answer my problem???